# How to add multiple results from loop to one array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, concatenation

I've a for loop in a while loop which give me after every iteration an array ("all_position_ro"). But in the end I need one summarized array with all results from every `iteration`.

```
position_ro = [12, 25, 42]
start = 1

while start < 2:

    for i in position_ro:

        nn_ro = [i + start]

        nn_ro_minus = [i - start]

        n_ro = numpy.array(nn_ro)

        n_ro_minus = numpy.array(nn_ro_minus)

        print(("n_ro:" + str(start) +":" + str(n_ro)))

        print(("n_ro_minus:" + str(start) +":" + 
        str(n_ro_minus)))



        summ_position_ro = numpy.concatenate((position_ro_array,n_ro), axis =1)

        all_position_ro = numpy.concatenate((summ_position_ro,n_ro_minus), axis =1)

        print(("all_position_ro:"  + str(all_position_ro)))

    start = start+1
```

## what I get:

```
position_ro:(array([12, 25, 42], dtype=int64),)

n_ro1:[[13 26 43]]

n_ro_minus1:[[11 24 41]]

all_position_ro:[[12 25 42 13 26 43 11 24 41]]



n_ro2:[[14 27 44]]

n_ro_minus2:[[10 23 40]]

all_position_ro:[[12 25 42 14 27 44 10 23 40]]
```

## what I need:

```
all_position_ro:[[12 25 42 13 26 43 11 24 41 14 27 44 10 23 40]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks over complicated, plus uses some variables that have not been declared (at least in what I can read) like `position_ro_array`.
To make it easier to read I would do

```py
position_ro_out = position_ro.tolist()
position_ro_out += [ii + 1 for ii in position_ro] + [ii - 1 for ii in position_ro] + [ii + 2 for ii in position_ro] + [ii - 2 for ii in position_ro]
position_ro_out = numpy.asarray(position_ro_out)
```

More compact (but maybe less readable)

```py
position_ro_out = np.concatenate((position_ro, np.asarray([[[ii + kk] for ii in position_ro] + [[ii - kk] for ii in position_ro] for kk in range(1, 3)]).flatten()))
```